# Error with trying to backward() through graph a second time in Pytorch

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

I have the following code which is causing me a problem:

```
    optimizer1 = torch.optim.LBFGS(my_neural_network.parameters(), lr=lr1)

    loss1=100.0
    loss2=0.0


    x = torch.tensor([200, 100, 0, 1, 15])
    for epoch in range(no_of_epochs+1):

        solution1 = my_neural_network(x)
        
        grads_sol = gradients(solution1, x)

        def CalculateLoss():
            loss1 = 0
         
            # Omitted code: I do something here which I will write as follows
            loss1 = function_special(solution1, grads_sol, x)
                     
            return loss1

 
        def closure():
            optimizer1.zero_grad()
            loss1 = calculateLosses()[0]
            loss1.backward()
            return loss1

        optimizer1.step(closure1)
        StepLR1.step()
```

When I run this, I get an error:

> Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
> Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

I tried adding retain_graph=True but it didn't help. I am confused about possibly needing to detach objects.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am not understanding you correctly, you don't have to back-prop through the graph more than once in this case. The output value needs to be re-computed in the closure. Otherwise, for a deterministic state-less loss function, what good would the closure function do?

I cannot see through your code but it should be something like this:

```py
optimizer1 = torch.optim.LBFGS(my_neural_network.parameters(), lr=lr1)

loss1=100.0

x = torch.tensor([200, 100, 0, 1, 15])
for epoch in range(no_of_epochs+1):

    def CalculateLoss(solution1, grads_sol, x):
        loss1 = 0
        
        # Omitted code: I do something here which I will write as follows
        loss1 = function_special(solution1, grads_sol, x)
                 
        return loss1

    def closure():
        optimizer1.zero_grad()
        solution1 = my_neural_network(x)
        grads_sol = gradients(solution1, x)
        loss1 = calculateLosses(solution1, grads_sol, x)[0]
        loss1.backward()
        return loss1

    optimizer1.step(closure1)
    StepLR1.step()
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I still get the problem. For the first epoch (epoch=0), it works. Then for the next epoch (epoch=1), I get the error when it reaches backward in the closure..

Comment: @math_guy there might be problems with the omitted code?

Comment: Right, do you have any intuition at all what it could be without seeing the code? I really thought that I had to do some detach() somewhere.